# Google Container Engine - How do I detect that requests to my service are health checks?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

On [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/), how do I detect that requests to my Web service, running behind an L7 load balancer, are in fact health checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Container Engine health checks are recognizable by the HTTP request header 'user-agent' having the value `GoogleHC/1.0`.

### Example Hapi.js code:

```
if ((request.headers['user-agent'] || '').toLowerCase().startsWith('googlehc')) {
  return reply('Healthy')
}
```

Comment: Yeah most times people want a different path,they just send 200 on "/" for that UA instead. You can also modify the healthy check directly in the console to point to whatever you want (compute engine>healthy checks). Note that on GCE the L7 healthy check is just a placeholder to keep the loadbalancer happy, it's health checking your vms, you should really specify a readiness probe on your endpoints so Kubernetes can health check the actual containers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on user specified parameters like user-agent, I think the standard for this is just to make a `/healthz` route that returns `200` if healthy. The internal Kubernetes components all do this.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case unfortunately. The health checks I receive are for path / AFAICT.

Comment: I tried adding a Hapi.js route for both /healthz and to print `request.path`, which both indicate that the request path is / (the /healthz route doesn't trigger and `request.path === '/'`).

Comment: @aknuds1 It won't change on it's own. You have to tell GCE to use the different path.